# What is the meaning of "${1#*-}" in BASH

Tags: bash

There is a if condition as below

```
if [ "${1#*-}" = "$1" ]; then
   echo "Do something"
fi
```

But could somebody explain what is the meaning of `${1#*-}` ?

Comment: Am missing the keyword for this in the answers below, its what you call [`Parameter expansion`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) in `bash`

Comment: Thank you for everyone for your participation in this question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`${1#*-}` deletes the shortest match of `*-`, a glob-like pattern from `$1` variable.

E.g. `abcdef-xyz-foo` -> `xyz-foo`

Your `if` check does actually:

```
if $1 does not contain '-'
```

Answer (score 17):

`*-` is a pattern matching a (possibly empty) string followed by a `-`. The `#` operator drops the *shortest* prefix matching `*-` from the expansion of `$1`. An example:

```
$ foo="123-456"
$ echo "${foo#*-}"
456
$ foo="123-456-789"
456-789
```

I emphasize shortest because there is a companion operator `##` that drops the *longest* matching prefix.

```
$ echo "${foo##*-}"
789
```

Answer (score 7):

This test if no have `"-"` in a parameter 1

See this:

```
test=jhonatan
if [ "${test#*-}" = "$test" ]; then 
    echo "yes" ; 
else 
    echo "no" ;
fi
```

This print yes because no have `"-"` in a string test

with this

```
test=jhonatan-piffer
```

The same script print no.

`${variable#pattern}` remove prefix pattern of string.

In this last case all string between start until `"-"`

```
echo ${test#*-}
```

result in:

```
"piffer"
```

and `"piffer"` differs from `"jhonatan-piffer"`

Read this for more information:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion